# Cannot read property 'array_name' of undefined - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to fetch data through Axios' request and push into an array. Here is my code:

```
props: [
      'products',
    ],
    data: function () {
      return {
        algolia: '',
        products_data : [],
      };
    },
mounted() {
        this.products_data = this.products;      
      }
methods: {
      find () {
        let new_product = {};

        axios.get('/product/find?barcode=' + this.barcode)
        .then(function (res) {
          new_product.name = resp.data.name
          new_product.barcode = resp.data.barcode
          new_product.unit = resp.data.unit

          this.products_data.push(new_product);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        })
     },
}
```

I am getting the error `Cannot read property 'products_data' of undefined` sue to this line `this.products_data.push(new_product);` I am new in Vue. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Regards

Comment: I don't know anyhting about vue but it seems like you create a new local scope in your `.then()` - function which no longer holds the reference to `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work, i have removed function syntax and used arrow function.

```
find () {
    let new_product = {};

    axios.get('/product/find?barcode=' + this.barcode)
    .then((resp) => {
      new_product.name = resp.data.name
      new_product.barcode = resp.data.barcode
      new_product.unit = resp.data.unit

      this.products_data.push(new_product);
    })
    .catch((err)=> {
      console.log(err);
    })
 }
```